# Azure Speech SDK transcibing audio problem

Tags: node.js, azure, discord, azure-cognitive-services, speech-to-text

I'm trying to add another way to transcribe speech to text to this npm lib `https://github.com/Rei-x/discord-speech-recognition` by using Azure speech to text SDK.  I tried using the api but also with the same result.  here's my code and what comes out of it

```
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");

function getAzureRequestOptions(options) {
    const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(options.key, options.region);
    if (options.lang) {
        speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = options.lang;
    }
    return speechConfig;
}

function resolveSpeechWithAzureSpeechToText(audioBuffer, options) {
    console.log('resolveSpeechWithAzureSpeechToText called with audioBuffer length:', audioBuffer.length);
    const pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream();

    pushStream.write(audioBuffer);
    pushStream.close();

    const speechConfig = getAzureRequestOptions(options);
    const audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(pushStream);
    const recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Starting recognition...');
        recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
            (result) => {
                console.log('Recognition succeeded');
                recognizer.close();
                resolve(result.text);
                console.log(result);
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('Recognition failed');
                recognizer.close();
                reject(err);
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
    });
}

module.exports.resolveSpeechWithAzureSpeechToText = resolveSpeechWithAzureSpeechToText;
```

As a result, I only get the length of the audio buffer with no text.

console view :

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with more details such as your output, expected output, input source, input format and any other detail that can help to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of the console, the input data (audioBuffer) is PCM mono with 48khz. The azure documentation says the input should be PCM 8 or 16khz with one channel. I tried 48-16 conversion but it didn't solve th problem. The console logs say that no speech was detected in the audio so I think the problem is with the audioBuffer. For now i want to get transcibed speech as text in console logs

Comment: Yes, it seems the issue with the input format. Can you provide the details on how do you trying to convert the audio?

Comment: I tried to change sample rate to 16000 in this file [link](https://github.com/Rei-x/discord-speech-recognition/blob/main/src/bot/voiceMessage/VoiceMessage.ts) but I don't know if this is the right way, I also tried to convert audio with some node library but I don't remember what exactly it was. From another file which handle WitAi speech to text, I read this `const contentType = "audio/raw;encoding=signed-integer;bits=16;rate=48k;endian=little";`

Comment: I don't know why, but earlier resampling didn't help, now its working fine i, I used for this waveResampler, here is the code `const resampledAudioBuffer = waveResampler.resample(audioBuffer, 48000, 16000);` thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For record, the issue is with the format of audio buffer (PCM mono with 48khz).

Based on documentation, the default audio streaming format is **WAV (16 kHz or 8 kHz, 16-bit, and mono PCM)**.

It seems the issue might be that the previous attempt to conversion might not have been implemented correctly or targeting a different format.

So, to fix the issue you can use [wave-resamper package](https://github.com/rochars/wave-resampler) or [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to convert the input audio into supported format.

```js
const waveResampler = require('wave-resampler');
// resample 48kHz samples to 16kHz
const resampledAudio = waveResampler.resample(inputAudio, 48000, 16000);
```

Comment: The conversion did not completely solve my problem, a few times I was able to get some result, but for the most part the effect was still the same as before, when I saved speech to wav file I noticed that the audio was slowed down a bit, I think this is done to achieve greater efficiency of transcribing, in any case, after converting 48 kHz to 16 kHz the audio was even more slowed down, so that it was actually impossible to understand. Only by converting every 48000 value to 16000 in the library files did it start to work properly and the audioBuffer did not require any conversion